# Fix "Route hash chain too long" without restart

Tags: networking, routing, cache

On our production server (ubuntu 12.04, 3.2.0-63 kernel) routing cache reached its capacity. Modifying `rhash_entries` is out of the question, since it is a kernel boot param, and we can not restart the server.

What are our options?

Machine has 8gb if ram (I know, very little, but it's an old one...).

Output of `grep . /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/*` looks like this:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/error_burst:1250
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/error_cost:250
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_elasticity:1
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_interval:60
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_min_interval:0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_min_interval_ms:0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_thresh:262144
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/gc_timeout:300
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/max_size:4194304
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/min_adv_mss:256
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/min_pmtu:552
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/mtu_expires:600
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/redirect_load:5
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/redirect_number:9
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/redirect_silence:5120
```

Comment: See the following link: http://serverfault.com/questions/106537/tuning-linux-ip-routing-parameters-secret-interval-and-tcp-mem

Comment: It sounds like you've already looked into this. Have you already tried increasing `net.ipv4.route.max_size` ?

Comment: @val0x00ff seen this, tried everything - but it is also a slightly different problem

Comment: @JoelDavis tried it, didn't work

Comment: Can you update with the contents of `/proc/net/stat/rt_cache` ?

Comment: @JoelDavis here http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5kue7DVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research and [reading this great article](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ipv4-route-cache-linux.html) I found temporary solutions: decreasing `net.ipv4.route.gc_timeout` so the entries from cache get removed faster, and decreasing `net.ipv4.route.gc_interval` so the garbage collector runs more often.

But these are all temporary, since on our machine it only solved the problem for a few hours and more intensive garbage collection took a lot of CPU. Watch out modifing these values - they can kill your machine.

Increasing `rhash_entries` seems to be the only way.

Comment: "increasing net.ipv4.route.gc_interval so the garbage collector runs more often"? Shouldn't it be *decreasing* this interval?